# 127.0.0.1 ha rechazado la conexión

Tags: python, django, web, localhost, conexión

He creado un nuevo proyecto con Django con `django-admin startproject Solver1`, posteriormente utilice `python manage.py migrate`, y por último `python manage.py runserver`. Me mostró la siguiente información:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 10, 2020 - 17:27:39
Django version 3.1.1, using settings 'Solver1.settings'
Starting development server at **http://127.0.0.1:8000/**
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

Utilicé la dirección que está en pantalla. Al entrar me aparece:

Vaya… no se puede obtener acceso a esta página 127.0.0.1 ha rechazado la conexión.

Comment: Estas tratando de conectarte desde el mismo equipo? Porque 127/8 es _todo_ para localhost. La siguiente pregunta es si estás usando el puerto correcto (dice usar el puerto 8000, si solo escribes `http://127.0.0.1`, no va a funcionar).

Comment: Hola, si estoy tratando de conectarme de mismo equipo y lo que hago es copiar la dirección que da el cmd y pegarla en el navegador (Microsoft Edge)

Comment: Debería funcionar. Como es güindous, no te puedo dar mucha ayuda en cuanto a cosas que podrías correr para verificar que el puerto este abierto.

Comment: Para probar el puerto se puede ejecutar "telnet 127.0.0.1" en linea de comandos de windows. Si el puerto no esta abierto deberia darle un error "Conectándose a 127.0.0.1...No se puede abrir la conexión al host, en puerto 8000: Error en la conexión", pero si está abierto deberia quedarle el prompt para enviarle datos al puerto

Comment: Si al intentar el telnet sale el error "telnet no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo ..." es porque no lo tiene habilitado. Para habilitarlo puede seguir los pasos indicados en https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/38433.windows-10-enabling-telnet-client.aspx

Comment: De pronto quizá podría ser la versión de Django, algunas versiones tienen este tipo de errores, pero déjalo como última opción.

Comment: se que el comando `netstat` está disponible en güindous, pero no conozco las opciones que hay que correr para ver los puertos abiertos.... _y_ si se va a probar con telnet, hay que especificar el puerto, porque el puerto por defecto que va a utilizar no es el 8000. `telnet localhost 8000`.

Answer (score 1):

Parece como si el servidor no estuviera corriendo. Prueba lo siguiente:

Inicia el servidor con `python manage.py runserver` y no presiones CTRL-C hasta que hayas comprobado en tu navegador si funciona o no. Si sigue sin funcionar prueba cambiando la dirección IP y/o puerto del servidor:

Abrir el servidor en otro puerto (p.ej: 8080):

```
python manage.py runserver 8080
```

Para usar todo el rango de IPs públicas:

```
python manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

Más info en la documentación oficial de Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server